# Nested useFetch in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

How do you accomplish nested fetching in Nuxt 3?
I have two API's. The second API has to be triggered based on a value returned in the first API.

I tried the code snippet below, but it does not work, since `page.Id` is `null` at the time it is called. And I know that the first API return valid data. So I guess the second API is triggered before the result is back from the first API.

```html
<script setup>
  const route = useRoute()
  const { data: page } = await useFetch(`/api/page/${route.params.slug}`)
  const { data: paragraphs } = await useFetch(`/api/page/${page.Id}/paragraphs`)
</script>
```

Obviously this is a simple attempt, since there is no check if the first API actually return any data. And it is not even waiting for a response.

In Nuxt2 I would have placed the second API call inside `.then()` but with this new Composition API setup i'm a bit clueless.

Comment: can you show us the serverside code?

Comment: @Ifaruki The server side code is not the issue here. The API return data. Lets just assume that both API calls are successful.

Comment: What version of Nuxt are you using? RC1 or 3? Try the other one.

Comment: At the moment I use `npm:nuxt3@latest` and that is `3.0.0-rc.3-27578655.a802b87`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could watch the `page` then run the API call when the page is available, you should `paragraphs` as a `ref` then assign the destructed data to it :

```html
<script setup>
const paragraphs = ref()

const route = useRoute()

const { data: page } = await useFetch(`/api/page/${route.params.slug}`)


watch(page, (newPage)=>{
    if (newPage.Id) {

      useFetch(`/api/page/${newPage.Id}/paragraphs`).then((response)=>{
         paragraphs.value  = response.data

     })
        
    }
}, {
    deep: true,
    immediate:true
})
</script>
```

Comment: what is deep and immediate attributes ?

Comment: `deep` means to watch the nested properties of an object or an array, `immediate` to trigger the watcher at the first rendering

Comment: and if there is an error how to process it ? because i have a big page error 500 :/

Answer (score 5):

You can set your 2nd `useFetch` to not immediately execute until the first one has value:

```html
<script setup>
  const route = useRoute()
  const { data: page } = await useFetch(`/api/page/${route.params.slug}`)
  const { data: paragraphs } = await useFetch(`/api/page/${page.value?.Id}/paragraphs`, {
    // prevent the request from firing immediately
    immediate: false,
    // watch reactive sources to auto-refresh
    watch: [page]
  })
</script>
```

You can also omit the `watch` option there and manually `execute` the 2nd `useFetch`.
But for it to be reactive, pass a function that returns a URL instead:

```js
const { data: page } = await useFetch(`/api/page/${route.params.slug}`)
const { data: paragraphs, execute } = await useFetch(() => `/api/page/${page.value?.Id}/paragraphs`, {
  immediate: false,
})

watch(page, (val) => {
  if (val.Id === 69) {
    execute()
  }
})
```

You should never invoke composables inside lifecycle hooks.

More `useFetch` options can be found [here](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch).

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to avoid using `await`. Also, use references to hold the values.  This will allow your UI and other logic to be reactive.

```html
<script setup>
  const route = useRoute()
  const page = ref()
  const paragraphs = ref()
  useFetch(`/api/page/${route.params.slug}`).then(it=> {
     page.value = it
     useFetch(`/api/page/${page.value.Id}/paragraphs`).then(it2=> {
        paragraphs.value = it2
     }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is a valid option but I think you lose access to things like `pending` and `refresh`, which are both pretty handy?