# How to access pending and data inside if statement nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have this template:

```
<template>
    <Loading v-if="pending" />
    <div v-else>
        <p>Title: {{ movie.title }}</p>
        <p>Imbd Rating: {{ movieImbd }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

And I have 2 requests

The first one:
`const { data: movie, pending } = await useFetch(url, { key: movieId });`

The second one inside if:

```
if (pending) {
    const { data: movieImbd, pending } = await useFetch(
        `https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${movie.value.imdb_id}&apikey=${config.ombdToken}`,
        { key: movie.value.imdb_id }
    );
}
```

My first question is: **How to get access to** `movieImbd` **inside if?**

My second question is: **How to use** `pending` **from second request in template?** Because I want content to be displayed after the data is loaded from the second request

I know that there is a fetchDelay in nuxt 2, but I did not find anything similar in version 3. Can I make a delay for a request in nuxt 3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested useFetch in Nuxt 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72419491/nested-usefetch-in-nuxt-3)

Comment: I have done this before, but I need to access `pending` from the second request

Comment: `<Loading v-if="!movieImbd" />` I can use `movieImbd` instead of `pending` but I still have question about `fetchDelay`